Хранение настроек в файле, многопоточность
Всем привет
Хочу сделать хранение настройек в json файле.
public interface ISettingsRepository<T> where T: new () 
{
    T Load();
    void Save(T settings);
}

public abstract class JsonFileSettingsRepository<T> : ISettingsRepository<T> where T : new ()
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    
    private readonly string _filePath = GetLocalFilePath($"{typeof(T).Name}.json");
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions = new()
    {
        WriteIndented = true
    };

    public T Load()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return File.Exists(_filePath)
                ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(_filePath)) ?? new T()
                : new T();
        }
    }

    public void Save(T settings)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(settings, _serializerOptions);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_filePath)!);
            File.WriteAllText(_filePath, json);
        }
    }
    
    private static string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); 
        var companyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        return Path.Combine(appData, companyName?.Company ?? Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Name ?? string.Empty, fileName);
    }
}

public class UserSettingsManager : JsonFileSettingsRepository<UserSettings>
{
}

Допустим кто-то один считает настройки, изменит их и пока решил не сохранять. Кто-то другой тоже считал настройки, модифицировал, сохранил. Первый решил сохранить. Естественно настройки последенего перезатерлись в файле.
Как написать код такой, чтоб такого не происходило? На ум приходит что-то типа файла .lock, но тогда доступа до настроек не будет у другого, пока первый не сохранит.
Либо определять, что файл был изменен (FileSystemWatcher) и пред сохранением считывать актуальное состояние, как-то мерджить эти настройки и сохранять (бред какой-то).
Вреоятно есть какое-то адекватное решение? Или проблема не такая уж проблема?

Если доступ к настройкам есть у нескольких пользователей, может это повод сделать какие-то их категории персональными для каждого?

Тут нет решения если один файл на двоих. Та же проблема в системах контроля версий  "пока редактировал файл кто-то другой закомитил". И там решение - мерж (вернее слияние чужого со своим или начать заново). Ну можно уведомить что настройки изменились - толку то. Блокировать на редактирование - человек забыл и не сохранил. Просто настройки не должны пересекаться. Иначе придется выбирать один из костылей - и все они плохие.

Ну для начала - кто такие "один" и "другой" и какого чёрта они имеют доступ на запись одного и того же файла? На первый взгляд ситуация не выглядит нормальной

@AlexanderSt проблема не пользователях, а , например, если настройки читают/пишут разные части программы. Читают в одно время,  а пишут чуть позже. Исходя из мыслей vitidev наверно нужно просто тщательно следить за использованием чтения записи настроек. Кажется каким-то хрупиким и хотелось бы как-то защититься.. Может существует иной подход?

@andreymal "один", "друогой"  - разные части одной программы. Проблема в разнесении во времени. чтения и записи. Вероятно есть другой правильный подход к этому делу.

Если программа одна, то и экземпляр настроек внутри неё должен быть один, вследствие чего проблема исчезает сама собой

@andreymal каким образом проблема исчезает? если один класс в считал настройки, модифицировал, не сохранил.. ждет чего-то. Второй класс считал, поменял, записал. И тут первый раздуплился и решил записать. Я теоретизирую.

После "модифицировал" изменения автоматически станут доступны всем классам программы, если экземпляр настроек действительно будет один. Ждать сохранения не нужно (а скорее всего даже сохранять не нужно, выполнить сохранение один раз в момент закрытия программы да и всё)

Решение может быть аналогичное базе данных. В базе данных для таких случаев есть транзакции и блокировка таблиц. Опять же ReaderWriterLock, про который я писал в удалённном ответе, может помочь. Если так важен монопольный доступ от чтения до записи, можно сначала заблокировать настройки, потом прочитать, потом записать, потом разблокировать.

@andreymal воот. Я примерно так и думаю. Считать, держать в памяти, сохранить при закрытии программы. Но только надо сделать это правильно =(
